# C++, object declaration in header files

Tags: c++, qt, class, header

I have some class, and in it I want to create object of another class ... 
Usually I do it in header file, I just put something like:

`QString RSSName;`

and it works because that class has constructor that has no parameters ...

So here's my problem: how do I do that for some class(let's say ErrorOutput) that has only constructor with 1 or more parameters? I don't want to create pointer to object, I need it to be something like this:

`ErrorOutput err("test");`

I hope I've described the question correctly, it's little sleepy over here :P

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Do you mean that you declare your own class in a header file, and declare a member variable?  e.g. `class Something { QString RSSName; ... };`

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Yeah, I wanted to declare a member variable :)

Comment: Ah, you want the [member initialization list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell from your description what exactly you are asking for, but it sounds like "RSSName" is a member variable in your class.  If I'm correct about that, initialize it in the constructor's initialization list.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : RSSName(someVal) { }

private:    
    QString RSSName;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted ... The sad thing is that I knew about this, but just couldn't remember. It's time to go to sleep and continue tomorrow :) Thanks !!